# How to suppress serverside logging of EJBExceptions which are bubbled up to the client?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging

My bean throws an Application Exception which I encapsulate in an EjbException. The EjbException then goes to the client. How can I suppress logging of EjbExceptions in my Glassfish APP Server ? Cause every Exception which goes to the client is logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple:

EJBExceptions are System Exceptions and are automatically logged by the EJB Container. If I want an Exception which is not logged server side I have to use Application Exceptions and "pollute" my interface.

```
public void create(Receiver receiver) throws ReceiverAllreadyExistsException, ReceiverLimitReachedException {
        testIfReceiverLimitReached(receiver);
        testIfReceiverAlreadyExists(receiver);
        getEntityManager().persist(receiver);

    }
```